# how can I load spring bean with hiberate mysql data spring-rest

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to perform validation in spring and for that I need some data to be available before I execute the validation. That data is in my sql inside the table . I am looking for solution which will load my spring bean from the mysql table and that bean I can use to get the data for the validation .

Comment: you have to use orm framework

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example.. you just need declare your validator as bean.

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidatorImpl.class)
@Documented
public @interface MyValidator {

    String message() default "invalid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}

@Component // <---- this will allow you to access spring component
public class MyValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, String> {

   @Autowired MyDAO myDAO;

   public void initialize(MyValidator constraint) {
   }

   public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: in this example we are injecting mydao which will have method to call for fetching data . but my question is I just need a POJO loaded with data during validation . correct me if I dont correctly your example

Comment: @abhinavjain you can have your pojo with `myDAO.loadData(string)` or I didn't understand you

Comment: thank you for your answer .I am looking something like this @Autowire MyPojo myPojo and after the injection I can use my pojo . loading of the pojo spring should handle . or may be I am expecting something that spring cannot provide I am not sure